# Git bash change default .ssh location

Tags: git, git-bash

I have been struggling to change .ssh location on git bash.

When I open Git Bash command prompt, I'm typing cd ~/.ssh then my Git Bash navigates to some H:/xyz/.ssh directory. I want to change it to some D:/user/.ssh directory. Sorry, I'm not experienced on UNIX but tried some ways found on internet in vain. Please advise.

Comment: which version (OS and GitBash) are you using? On Windows7 with version 1.8.1.2-preview20130201 i am in my /c/Users/<username> folder after typing "cd ~/.ssh"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm on Windows XP and GitBash version 1.8.3 preview20130601.

Comment: what does "echo $HOME" output? Is your home folder on some network share (H:) maybe? Company policy? Just tried with version 1.8.3-preview20130601 and it correctly goes into $HOME/.ssh

Comment: Spot on! It is set to H:/xyz. How can I change this to elsewhere?

Comment: For those who still face the issue, search `etc/passwd` under git-bash installation path. There could be an entry associated with your system username. If you find `H:/xyz` or `/h/xyz` in it, change it to the expected path.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to change your HOME variable (containing the path to your home directory) you can try different approaches.

The linux "inhouse" solution would be to edit your ~/.bashrc file (or create it) to say something like

```
export HOME="/d/user"
```

Next time you start GitBash, and type

```
cd ~/.ssh
```

it will go into /d/user/.ssh if the directory exists.

Now according to [danlimerick](http://danlimerick.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/git-for-windows-tip-setting-home-and-the-startup-directory/) and [GregK](http://gregk.me/2011/change-gitbash-home-directory/) you can also set the HOME variable directly in Windows. The links also mention how you can change the startup folder via changing the shortcut properties.

Similar questions with answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560064/git-bash-home-directory-different-from-git-extension-than-git-bash) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017143/git-bash-how-to-default-to-other-directory-instead-of-home-directory).