# Why does ssh try to read files at a non-existent shared path?

Tags: git, ssh, git-bash

Since a few days ago, I've noticed that ssh cannot work in `git-bash`. Commands like `git push`, `git ls-remote`, `git fetch` in a repository with an ssh-protocol remote just hang. The ssh is the one embedded in `git-bash`. Besides, SSH CLI like `ssh -p 29418 $username@$gerrithost` does not work either. The repository URL with https-protocol works well. But our Gerrit only supports ssh-protocol.

I try `strace` and find it reads `.ssh/config` under a path that looks like a samba path

```
35  742476 [main] ssh 17432 mount_info::conv_to_win32_path: src_path //172.xx.xx.xx/share/AAAA/BBBB/.ssh/config, dst \\172.xx.xx.xx\share\AAAA\BBBB\.ssh\config, flags 0x6020, rc 0
```

After specifying config, private key and known_hosts, SSH CLI works.

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=~/.ssh/known_hosts -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -F ~/.ssh/config -p 29418 $username@$gerrithost
```

I also set `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`, and git commands don't get stuck. But they have new issues. I want to figure out why ssh does not read files at `~/.ssh` by default.

I can browse `\\172.xx.xx.xx` but `share` does not exist. I guess ssh uses some environment variable whose value represents the path that holds the default `.ssh/`, and the value now is `\\172.xx.xx.xx\share\AAAA\BBBB`. To my understanding, the default path is `$HOME`. But `echo $HOME` prints `/d/Users/myname`. Besides, I suspect that our IT administrators have configured something behind us. I have asked them to fix this issue, but they have no clue yet.

What are the other possible variables that have higher precedence than `HOME`? Maybe it's not a variable. What possible config values could have the effect and where could they be set? Thanks for any help.

Comment: One obvious candidate is `GIT_SSH`

Comment: @tripleee `GIT_SSH` is not set. I never set any long-lasting `GIT_` variable on this machine. When a variable is necessary, I add it before the command.

Answer (score 0):

After reading these questions, [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702660/git-bash-change-default-ssh-location), [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560064/git-bash-home-directory-different-from-git-extension-than-git-bash), I think it's related with git-bash.

I run a full grep in my git-bash installation path and try to find `172.xx.xx.xx`. At last, an entry is found in `etc/passwd`. It ends with `//172.xx.xx.xx/share/AAAA/BBBB:/usr/bin/bash`. I change it to `/d/Users/myname:/usr/bin/bash` and the issue is fixed.

As for the entries in `etc/passwd`, I guess some actions invoke to generate or update `etc/passwd` following IT policies.