# How do I execute a .bat from git bash and then return to the console?

Tags: windows, git, cmd, git-bash

I have created a goToProject.bat file with this content:

```
cd C:\Dev\MyProject
```

I want to run the goToProject.bat using Git Bash because i don't want to manually go to the folder every time i have to use git in my project.

To run the goToProject.bat from Git Bash i can do that:

```
$cmd goToProject.bat
```

Doing this the goToProject.bat runs but the console transforms to the windows cmd console and if i do:

```
c:\Dev\MyProject> exit
```

The console transforms again to Git Bash console but in the default route.

How i can run the goToProject.bat and stay in the Git Bash console?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already found what I needed:

To open git bash directly from visual studio without having to manually type the project root folder every time, just add a new external tool command:

- In Visual Studio Menu Bar: Tools -> External Tools -> Add New
- **Title**: Git Bash
- **Command**: c:\Program Files (x86)\git\bin\sh.exe
- **Args**: --login -i
- **Initial Dir**: $(SolutionDir)

Doing this, you can search 'Git Bash' under 'Tools' on the Visual Studio Menu Bar and git bash will be opened within your project folder.

Also, you can set a shortcut to your external tools:

- In Visual Studio Menu Bar: Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard
- In Show commands containing type: Tools.ExternalCommand
- Choose the command you want (the number of the external tool is the position in the list) * Set a shortcut for it (e.g, Ctrl+G, Ctrl+B)

Answer (score 1):

Just write up a .sh script instead of a .bat file.

Here's more info:
[GIT Bash - how to default to other directory instead of home directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017143/git-bash-how-to-default-to-other-directory-instead-of-home-directory)