# Change git default directory

Tags: git, directory, default

Just as the title says. How can i change the default starting directory for git? I searched for it here but couldn't really find an clear answer. What i'm not trying to do is clone it to another directory

I also think that with a simple answer this could be a good question for others.

Comment: What do you mean by starting directory? If you run `git init` it initialises a repo in the current folder. There isn't a default.

Comment: I had the same question. Maybe you don't want the `.git` directory or you don't like the default name.. Don't know

Comment: i am using xampp. When i start git bash i must use cd to go the directory which my repo is in. Isn't there a way that it allways automatically starts in the right dir

Comment: You can have bash `cd` to a directory for you, with a command in your `.bashrc` file.  But this is a bad idea: what happens once you have three different repos?  It keeps changing directory to that first one, when you want it to work over here in the second or third.

Comment: probaly all my repos will be in my xampp htdocs folder so also for the future this saves a lot of effort

Comment: Checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017143/git-bash-how-to-default-to-other-directory-instead-of-home-directory

Answer (score 0):

On windows you can give shortcuts a starting directory.  From your bash prompt, do `cd /bin; start .` and make a shortcut to the `bash.exe` you see there; then set the shortcut's starting directory as you like.